# Does TUN interface support recvmmsg/sendmmsg to receive/send multiple messages in a single system call

Tags: c, linux, tun

sendmmsg/recvmmsg provide the option to send and receive multiple packets on socket in a single system call. Are these operations supported for TUN adaptor on Linux using C socket API.

Here is the sample code I tried but get errno=Socket operation on non-socket

```
    struct mmsghdr hdrs[ARRAY_SIZE];
    unsigned char data[ARRAY_SIZE][BUFF_SIZE];
    struct iovec iovecs[ARRAY_SIZE];
    
    memset(hdrs, 0, sizeof(hdrs));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        iovecs[i].iov_base = data[i];
        iovecs[i].iov_len = BUFF_SIZE;
        hdrs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iov = &iovecs[i];
        hdrs[i].msg_hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
    }
    
    while (true)
    {
        LOG_DEBUG(log__) << "blocking to read on fd=" << fd;
    
        int retVal = recvmmsg(fd, hdrs, ARRAY_SIZE, 0, NULL);
        LOG_DEBUG(log__) << "retVal=" << retVal;
        if (retVal < 0)
        {
            LOG_ERROR(log__) << "failed in recvmmsg, retVal=" << retVal << ", errno=" << strerror(errno);
            continue;
        }
        LOG_DEBUG(log__) << "read " << retVal << " messages";
                                                                                                                                                                       
        for (int i = 0; i < retVal; i++)
        {
            LOG_DEBUG(log__) << "read data of length " << hdrs[i].msg_len;                                                                                             
        }
    }
```

Comment: [here's a page on TUN/TAP devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tuntap.html#multiqueue-tuntap-interface) that says they support multiqueueing. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @CarsonGraham No. This option I am already tried and it works fine. This will provide the ability to read/write from multiple threads on the same TUN adaptor. I was looking a step further if it was possible to send/receive multiple packets using a single call to sendmmsg/recvmmsg like possible for UDP sockets. 

I tried out a sample program using recvmmsg to read multiple packets from the TUN fd and am getting errno=Socket operation on non-socket.

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question. Do send/recv work or do you have to use read/write?

Comment: `recvmmsg(fd` - how is `fd` created? Please create an [MCVE]. There are also `writev` and `readv`

Comment: @user253751 :) recv does not work. I have to use read on the file descriptor

Comment: Then it seems like you answered your own question. If you want this feature, maybe you can write it and send the Linux project a patch.